# Dropdown menu with few options for comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I stuck on one problem and would really appreciate your hint. I've got a typical PHP loop which is populating comments for thread as:

```
<tr><td>'.comment_date'.</td><td>'.comment_author.'</td><td>'.comment_content'.</td></tr>
```

Now, each populated `<tr>` and has additional `<td>` on his right which is a dropdown-menu presented as small icon, with options (listed as `<li>`). One of these options is "Reply to Comment", so that people can not only reply to the main thread, they would be able to reply to comment, which will be indented. The entire `<table>` is surrounded by `<form>` of course, for having some logic possibilities into inserting and processing response to comments.

Now the question is, how do I tell jQuery - where he listens for that form submit, for which comment -- `<tr>` -- dropdown item (like reply to comment) was clicked? So that I POST reference comment id and content for that particular row? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll just make sure that I made that clear: dropdown is here <tr><td>'.comment_date'.</td><td>'.comment_author.'</td><td>'.comment_content'.</td><td>dropdown-menu</td></tr>

Comment: `onClick="doSomething(this.id);"` - Will pass the ID of the clicked element to the function.

Comment: You can also pass just `this` to gain access to the entire element within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On clicking reply to comment set a value in a hidden field where you can set the id needed for posting the data. You can build your logic with this for multiple comments as well.

```
<td><select name = 'dropdown_1'>
...
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type='button' id = '1' value='reply' onclick = 'setId(this.id)' />
</td>
```

make sure both the character next to name of  tag ('dropdown_') and the id for the reply buttons have the same values, preferably use the database id value of the thread for easy flow. Set the id values of the different reply clicks in a single common hidden field separated by delimiter like a `,`.

On php side explode the hidden element values using the delimiter and out of all the dropdown values received via $_POST update the values of dropdowns which are in the list of ids received from the hidden field.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but then each of populated elements have the same hidden input name, and different value. When I post it, array received has plenty of these elements, and different ids, so I still don't know which dropdown menu for which of them was used :/

Comment: Can I have one more question?

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
     function test(id){
         $("#comments_menu_drop").on("click", "li", function(event) {
             console.log('clicked:'+id);
             id = '';
         })
     };
</script>
This basically works, I see on the console ID of the comment that I clicked, but when I click different one -- nothing, second -- nothing, third -- nothing, and usually on fourth -- works, and shows me all I clicked, and were somehow lagged, any idea why?

Comment: Fixed it, had duplicated onclick around dropdown menu within the function. Removed it, and left only console.log('clicked:'+id); which works now :) have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'this' object to identify which li is clicked.